# Can I use a filtering kit with sanke kegs?

Tags: kegerator, kegs, filtering

I just built a d-coupler kegerator, and picked up a few pony sanke kegs from a friend.  I've been looking to start filtering some of my homebrew, but all the kits I see online require soda kegs.  Is it possible to use the filter kits with a sanke keg, or is there some technical difference that would make it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Its still keg to keg filtering.  You'll need to use different fittings from keg to tubing but operationally, its the same thing.

Comment: I read somewhere that a brewer had to switch the gas and liquid fittings, have you heard anything about that?